# How to add a dropdown menu using HTML and CSS

Tags: css, html

I want to use a href for the nav-menu instead of using a div class, so when 'menu' is clicked, link1, link2, and link3 appear as a drop-down list. My code is listed below ("ex7.css and ex7mobile.css" code is the same). I know there is a way of doing it using div class however I have been told to do it using href.

```css
.clicker {
width:30px;
height:20px;
outline:none;
cursor:pointer;
}

.hiddendiv{
display:none;
height:70px;
}

.clicker:focus + .hiddendiv{
display:block;
}

header {
  display: block;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
}

.box {
 background-color: red;
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
 margin-left: 0px;
 transition: margin-left 1s;
}

#menu:target .box {
 margin-left: 100px;
 background-color: green;

.content {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.shownav {
  background-color: white;
  height: 5px;
  width: 20px;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 0px white,
  0px -10px 0px white;
}

nav {
  width: 20%;
  display: table-cell;
  background-color: yellow;
}

main {
  width: 60%;
  display: table-cell;
  background-color: darkblue;
  color: white;
}

div {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  display: table-cell;
  width: 20%;
}

footer {
  clear: both;
  background-color: darkgreen;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>My Web Page!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="ex7.css"
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="ex7mobile.css"/>
media="screen and (max-width: 700px)" />
  </head>
  <body id="menu">
    <header>
      <h1>Heading</h1>
    </header>

<div class="content">
<a class="shownav"></a>

<a href="#menu" class="on">Menu</a>
<a href="#" class="off">Close</a>
<div class="box"></div>

<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>


    <main>
      <p>My website</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim.</p>

<p>Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum.</p>

<p>Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc.</p>
    </main>

    <div>
      Right hand side
    </div>
</div>

    <footer>
      &copy; Your Name 2017
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code seems to be wrong.

Comment: Well, you don't say @PraveenKumar :L

Comment: @SølveTornøe So well, what should do bud?

Comment: I just found it funny that you said his code had to be wrong.. I just assumed it was obvious by the fact that he asked this type of question haha. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this in HTML5:

```html
<details>
  <summary><a href="#"> Menu</a></summary>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</details>
```

Or using Javascript:

```js
 
function toggle() {
 var ele = document.getElementById("toggleText");
 var text = document.getElementById("displayText");
 if(ele.style.display == "block") {
      ele.style.display = "none";
   }
 else {
  ele.style.display = "block";
 }
}
```

```html
<a id="displayText" href="javascript:toggle();">Menu</a>
<span id="toggleText" style="display: none">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</span>
```